# How can I delete the content in a tkinter Frame

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("face")
    w=root.winfo_screenwidth()
    h=root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.geometry("%dx%d" % (w, h))

    def openimage(): #in this part I just want to keep just one picture in Frame
        fname = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        image = Image.open(fname)
        (width, height)=image.size
        if width>=height:
            new_width=t1.winfo_width()
            new_height=int(height*t1.winfo_width()/width)
            image = image.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        else:
            new_height=t1.winfo_height()
            new_width=int(width*t1.winfo_height()/height)
            image = image.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        img = Label(t1, image=render)
        img.image = render
        img.place(x=0, y=0)

    def finish():
        exit()


    menubar = Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=menubar)

    menu1 = Menu(root)
    menu1.add_command(label='openphoto', command=openimage)
    menu1.add_command(label='get')
    menu1.add_command(label='save')

    menu2 = Menu(root)
    menu2.add_command(label='read')
    menu2.add_command(label='training')

    menu3 = Menu(root)
    menu3.add_command(label='openphotos')
    menu3.add_command(label='dis')

    menu4 = Menu(root)
    menu4.add_command(label='quit', command=finish)

    menubar.add_cascade(label="catch", menu=menu1)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="train", menu=menu2)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="distinguish", menu=menu3)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="exit", menu=menu4)



    t1=Frame(width=500,height=500, bg='gray')
    t1.grid(padx=100, pady=100)

    root.mainloop()



if __name__ =='__main__':

    main()
```

I want to clear the content in Frame, or let the former picture not show in the Frame while I choose another picture. Each time a picture is selected, it has nothing to do with the parameters used in the last selection. So I want to empty a Frame every time I choose a picture. I have tried in many ways. I don't know how to clear it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clear the widgets from a tkinter `Frame()` instance `frame`, you can use the following code:

```
for widget in frame.winfo_children():
    widget.destroy()
```

---

[`frame.winfo_children()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_children-method) returns a list of all the widgets in `frame`, then we loop through them and `destroy()` them all.

Comment: Artemis, you are a legend!